# Avoid creating branch pattern in GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, devops

We have protected branch pattern with wild character `relapp*` in GitLab. However developers want to create feature branches with JIRA number. Sometimes they put word `relapp` within the feature branches which will automatically fall into protected branches.

I want to avoid developers to create branches which contains `relapp` but not owners or maintainers. Any idea?